# Instantiating a class from a script elsewhere on the server OR: accessing const variables in script

Tags: php, apache, oop, web-development-server

I'm having trouble with instantiating a class from within a script. My code basically looks like this:

ConstAttributes.php located on server at e.g. `/var/www/abc/def/`

```
<?php
  namespace My\Path;

  class ConstAttributes {
    const ONE = "some";
    const TWO = "text";
    const THREE = "here";
  }
?>
```

index.php located elsewhere on server at e.g. `/var/www/xyz/123/`

```
<?php
  use My\Path\ConstAttributes;
  $aInst = new My\Path\ConstAttributes();
?>
```

I also tried:

```
use My\Path\ConstAttributes;
$aInst = new ConstAttributes();
```

but same result. I'm testing this live on an apache2 server. apache ist configured to point on the index page. When I'm refreshing the page, it's just blank - nothing on it. Everything that comes after I create the instance just isn't displayed at all; seems like the script hung himself up there. When I do something like this:

```
use My\Path\ConstAttributes;
//$aInst = new My\Path\ConstAttributes();
echo 'test';
```

I do get the echo message as expected.

**The point in doing this** is accessing the `const` variables in the index.php script. Before trying to instantiate the class, I tried `ConstAttributes::ONE` but that's dying there like it's doing when I'm instantiating the class.

I've googled quite alot now but couldn't solve the problem. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as first try - add `require_once('/var/www/abc/def/ConstAttributes.php');` at the beginning of `index.php`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I tried `echo 'test';` `require_once('/var/www/abc/def/ConstAttributes.php');` `echo 'test';` and only get echoed the first 'test'. After that, it hung himself up again, blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to use a constant within the php class, the php engine throws an exception " Notice: Use of undefined constant ONE - assumed 'ONE' in...". To work around this problem one can define and use the global constant. Please see the demo code here.

```
//
<?php
/*
* mypath\ConstAttributes.php
*/
namespace MyPath2;
//
define("ONE1", "One1");
const TWO2 = "Two2";
define("SIX", "Six6");
const SEVEN = "Seven7";
define("EIGHT", "Eight8");
const ONE = "some";
const TWO22 = "text2";
define("TWO", "text");
const THREE = "here";
//
/**
* Description of ConstAttributes
*
* @author B
*/
class ConstAttributes {
var $one = ONE;
var $two = TWO;
var $three = THREE;
var $two2 = TWO2;
var $four = "four4";
var $five = "five5";
var $seven = SEVEN ;
var $eight = EIGHT ;

function MyOne(){
    return ONE1;
}
function MyTwo(){
    return $this->two2;
}
function MyThree(){
    return $this->three;
}
function MyFour(){
    return $this->four;
}
function MySeven(){
    return $this->seven;
}
}
//
```

Once you have done that, then you can use your class as normal with index.php.

```
//
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
index.php
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    use MyPath2\ConstAttributes;
    include 'mypath\ConstAttributes.php';
    $aInst = new ConstAttributes();
    echo gettype($aInst)."<br>";
    echo $aInst->MyOne()."<br>";
    echo $aInst->MyTwo()."<br>";
    echo $aInst->MyFour()."<br>";
    echo $aInst->five."<br>";
    echo SIX."<br>";
    echo $aInst->MySeven()."<br>";
    echo $aInst->eight."<br>";
    echo "////////////////////////<br>";
    echo $aInst->one."<br>";
    echo TWO."<br>";
    echo $aInst->MyThree()."<br>";
    echo "///////////////////////////<br>";
    //echo TWO22."<br>";
    echo "///////////////////////////<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
//
```

The tested output is as follow:

```
//////////////////output////////////
// object
// One1
// Two2
// four4
// five5
// Six6
// Seven7
// Eight8
////////////////////////
// some
// text
// here
///////////////////////////
///////////////////////////
//
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your submission! That actually helped me alot and I ended up building it quite similar to this one!